# Modal con varias imagenes

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una vista en MVC, que es de un proyecto, este proyecto puede tener de 1 a 5 imagenes, lo que quiero es hacer que al clickear una imagen, se haga un modal, pero soy bastante nuevo en front-end y no me esta saliendo. Encontre codigo html, css y js, me funciona si lo aplico a una sola imagen pero no se como hacerlo para que se aplique a todas. Les muestro lo que tengo.
Vista:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen1 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                        <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail modall" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen1)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                                    <div id="caption"></div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen2 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                        <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail modall" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen2)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
```

Ese switch, va de 1 a 5, pero no paso todo el codigo porque es lo mismo desde el case 2 a 5. Y este es el script que estoy usando:

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Tambien tiene unos estilos de css, [lo saque de aca](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img). Si ven, el modal esta nomas en el case 1, y ese funciona bien, pero estuve tratando de hacer que este en todos los cases, pero no pude hacerlo funcionar. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: si si en el case 2 agregas el modal de nuevo ? como lo tienes en el case 1 ?

Comment: Si lo agregue pero no funciono.

Comment: en el JS tienes que buscar la imagen dinamicamente ya que solo estas enviando la `img01`, tienes que agregar el modal a los demas CASE y buscar la imagen que pertenece a cada case, por eso solo te funciona con el primero

Comment: Probe agregando eso, pero no me funciono, probablemente hice algo mal porque estoy empezando de a poco en JS. Me podrias dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: Listo, voy a realizar un ejemplo pero en html en simple ya tu tratas de organizarlo a  **asp.net-mvc**

Comment: Te lo agradeceria muchisimo!